# JTextField.getText() returns an empty String

Tags: java, string, swing, jtextfield, gettext

I am trying to create a window which allows the user to create a new student. The problem here is whenever the user presses the Save button:

```
private void btnSaveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    controlador.btnSaveClic(evt);
}
```

Then, the method btnSaveClic:

```
public void btnSaveClic(ActionEvent evt){
    this.save();
}
```

And the method save()

```
private void save() {
    String name = this.window.getTxtfName().getText().trim();
    String lastName = this.window.getTxtfLastName().getText().trim();
    String CX = this.window.getTxtfCX().getText().trim();
    int dni;
    String dn1= this.window.getTxtfDNI().trim();
    System.out.println("name"+name+" last name"+lastName+" DNI"+dn1+" CX"+CX);
    try
        {
        dni = Integer.parseInt(dn1.trim());
        System.out.println(dni);
        String result = gestor.newStudent(name, lastName, dni, CX);
        if (result.equals(EXITO_ALUMNOS)){
            this.window.dispose();
        }    
        if (result.equals(FAIL_ALUMNOS)){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, resultado, resultado, JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException nfe)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Missing data", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
}
```

I've also tried to make the getters obtain the text in the text fields, and return the strings, but everything is empty anyways. Eventually the output, at every case, would be:

`name last name DNI CX`

The problem is not on the newStudent method, because it never actually reaches that point, since the textFields are considered as empty, no matter what.

Comment: The most probable reason would be that there is a different set of textfields visible on the screen compared to what the `getTxtfXy()` methods provide. The issue itself can not be reproduced from these code snippets, a [mre] would be needed for that. Side note: `getTxtfDNI().trim()` is fishy: `JTextField` has no `trim()` as I know, that is a method of strings.